# How to use StackAlloc in x64?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am trying to use `StackAlloc` from `Graphics32` in DelphiXE7 in `X64` however it crashes with erorr. I tried adding `NOFRAME` to the code and that didn't help either.

`First chance exception at $000000000013FF10. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION'. Process Stack.exe (4536)`

```
program Stack;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

function StackAlloc(Size: Integer): Pointer; register;
asm
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
        POP       ECX          // return address
        MOV       EDX, ESP
        ADD       EAX, 3
        AND       EAX, not 3   // round up to keep ESP dword aligned
        CMP       EAX, 4092
        JLE       @@2
@@1:
        SUB       ESP, 4092
        PUSH      EAX          // make sure we touch guard page, to grow stack
        SUB       EAX, 4096
        JNS       @@1
        ADD       EAX, 4096
@@2:
        SUB       ESP, EAX
        MOV       EAX, ESP     // function result = low memory address of block
        PUSH      EDX          // save original SP, for cleanup
        MOV       EDX, ESP
        SUB       EDX, 4
        PUSH      EDX          // save current SP, for sanity check  (sp = [sp])
        PUSH      ECX          // return to caller
{$ELSE}
        .NOFRAME
        MOV       RAX, RCX
        POP       R8           // return address
        MOV       RDX, RSP     // original SP
        ADD       ECX, 15
        AND       ECX, NOT 15  // round up to keep SP dqword aligned
        CMP       ECX, 4092
        JLE       @@2
@@1:
        SUB       RSP, 4092
        PUSH      RCX          // make sure we touch guard page, to grow stack
        SUB       ECX, 4096
        JNS       @@1
        ADD       ECX, 4096
@@2:
        SUB       RSP, RCX
        MOV       RAX, RSP     // function result = low memory address of block
        PUSH      RDX          // save original SP, for cleanup
        MOV       RDX, RSP
        SUB       RDX, 8
        PUSH      RDX          // save current SP, for sanity check  (sp = [sp])
{$ENDIF}
end;

{ StackFree pops the memory allocated by StackAlloc off the stack.
- Calling StackFree is optional - SP will be restored when the calling routine
  exits, but it's a good idea to free the stack allocated memory ASAP anyway.
- StackFree must be called in the same stack context as StackAlloc - not in
  a subroutine or finally block.
- Multiple StackFree calls must occur in reverse order of their corresponding
  StackAlloc calls.
- Built-in sanity checks guarantee that an improper call to StackFree will not
  corrupt the stack. Worst case is that the stack block is not released until
  the calling routine exits. }

procedure StackFree(P: Pointer); register;
asm
{$IFDEF CPUX86}
        POP       ECX                     { return address }
        MOV       EDX, DWORD PTR [ESP]
        SUB       EAX, 8
        CMP       EDX, ESP                { sanity check #1 (SP = [SP]) }
        JNE       @Exit
        CMP       EDX, EAX                { sanity check #2 (P = this stack block) }
        JNE       @Exit
        MOV       ESP, DWORD PTR [ESP+4]  { restore previous SP  }
@Exit:
        PUSH      ECX                     { return to caller }
{$ELSE}
        POP       R8                       { return address }
        MOV       RDX, QWORD PTR [RSP]
        SUB       RCX, 16
        CMP       RDX, RSP                 { sanity check #1 (SP = [SP]) }
        JNE       @Exit
        CMP       RDX, RCX                 { sanity check #2 (P = this stack block) }
        JNE       @Exit
        MOV       RSP, QWORD PTR [RSP + 8] { restore previous SP  }
 @Exit:
        PUSH      R8                       { return to caller }
{$ENDIF}
end;

var
  SL: ^TStringList;
begin
  SL := StackAlloc(SizeOf(TStringList)); // Crashes here.
  SL^ := TStringList.Create;
  SL^.Add('sda');
  FreeAndNil(SL^);
  StackFree(sl);
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Are you sure you got latest GR32 1.9.1 version? Because my version looks quite different.

Comment: @iamjoosy Yep I got `graphics32-1-9-1-fixes-r2148.zip`

Comment: You should give this one a try: [GR32_LowLevel](http://sourceforge.net/p/graphics32/code/HEAD/tree/branches/Graphics32%201.9.1%20Fixes/Source/GR32_LowLevel.pas) it's r2187

Comment: Forget my last comment, it is also broken in r2187

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your version of `StackAlloc` lacks `PUSH R8` at the end of x64 version.
Due to this, the return address is not put back on the stack.