# How to implement alloc() in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

How can I implement a stack allocation method `alloc()` using assembly in Delphi? It isn't even exported from `msvcrt.dll` the way `malloc/free` is.

Comment: `getmem` should work

Comment: @PeterRader that allocates on heap.

Comment: For a start, details matter. The function is called `alloca`. Be precise. Get some ideas on how to do it from the code in Grids.pas, perhaps named StackAlloc IIRC, which I probably don't. It's dangerous to do this though. Easy to stomp on the compiler. Are you sure you need to do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are you sure that's the same method as the one found in GCC, MSVC? The one in Delphi requires free. But the `alloca` doesn't.

Comment: Am I sure that what is what? Again be precise.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan These are not the same methods. `StackAlloc` in Delphi requires `StackFree` yet the `alloca()` in C++ doesn't.

Comment: I thought you wanted to allocate memory on the stack. Was I wrong? In any case, I think calling StackFree is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a functioning implementation of `StackAlloc` in the graphics32 library. This supports x86 and x64 targets.

I learned this from a websearch which took me here: [How to use StackAlloc in x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809091/how-to-use-stackalloc-in-x64)

The other well known implementation that I am aware of can be found in the `Grids` unit of the VCL.